# Объясните, пожалуйста, как работают здесь два split() в одной строчке

Tags: python

Помогите понять, как здесь работает метод `split()`:

```
for i in file.readlines(): 
        for key in i.decode('cp1251').split('\t')[3].split(','):
```

Это часть кода, но не могу понять что за `[3]`? И если `\t` - это табуляция, то почему она не работает здесь:

```
a = 'qwer   asd 1   qwer'
b = a.split('/t')
print(b)
```

Вывод: `['qwer   asd 1   qwer']`

Буду благодарен за развернутый ответ, спасибо.

Comment: `'/t' != '\t'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверять нужно так:

```
a = 'qwer\tasd\t1\tqwer' # не 'qwer   asd 1   qwer'
b = a.split('\t')        # не '/t' - это не табуляция, а два символа '/' и 't'
print(b)
```

Код работает так:

```
i.decode('cp1251'). # перевести строку из кодировки Windows Cyrillic
split('\t')[3].     # разбить по знакам табуляции и взять четвёртую часть
split(',')          # ... которую разбить по запятым
```

Ваш код имеет смысл доработать:

```
# перекодировать файл надо при чтении, после может оказаться поздно
with open(filename, encoding='cp1251') as f:
    # readlines() не нужен, читать по строкам можно так
    for i in file:
        # 'bla\tbla\tbla\tkey1,key2\tbla\t...' -> key1, key2
        for key in i.split('\t')[3].split(','):
            ...
```

Answer (score 5):

1 метод разделяет строку через `\t` на список. Цифра `[3]` означает, что мы берём 4-ый (расчёт с нуля!) элемент списка и разделяем его на ещё один список через запятую.

А не работает у вас потому, что табуляция = один особый длинный пробел.
Помог?